# How to pass string variable to function in shell?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have method that should receive string, but it does not work as intended

```
receive_string()
{
    local string=$1         
    echo "$string"
}
```

When I call it I get unrelated error.

```
receive_string "Catch a string my friend!"
```

Returns:

> 4: local: friend!: bad variable name

Instead of

> Catch a string my friend!

What is the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that variable expansion is literal in bash, so
`local string=$1` will behave as `local string=Catch a string my friend!`.

It is a good practice to enclose between double quotes your string variables, so they don't separate during expansion. Try this:

```sh
local string="$1"
```

It won't add quotes to your string and it will keep it together.

About the `!` specific behavior, check KamilCuk's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are **not** running your script with `bash`. You are running your script under `dash` shell. The behavior does not happen on `bash` - in `bash` the command `local` is very specially handled like ex. `export` and arguments have same semantics as on assignment. Most probably the shebang of your script is `#!/bin/sh` and `sh` is linked to `dash` on your system. Use shebang with `bash` to run `bash`.

> ```
> local string=$1
> ```

is expanding `$1` so it becomes:

```
 local string=Catch a string my friend!
```

which creates a variable `string` with value `Catch`, empty variables `a` `string` and `my` and `friend!` is invalid variable value.

As always, quote variable expansion.

```
local string="$1"
```

Research when to quote variables in shell. Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Side note: the `!` in `"something!"` triggers [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) *in bash*. In bash when in interactive shell with history expansion enabled, you would put it ex. in single quotes `"something"'!'`.